# Remove multiple redundant spaces that are not part of a string literal

Tags: c#

I'm trying to find a function that removes redundant consecutive spaces if unless the space is within a string literal, denoted by a single or double quote.

```
    string source   = "sqlcmd.exe    -Q \"LEAVE     SQL TEXT HERE   UNCHANGED BECAUSE IT'S IN A DBL QUOTE BLOCK\"";
    string expected = "sqlcmd.exe -Q \"LEAVE     SQL TEXT HERE   UNCHANGED BECAUSE IT'S IN A DBL QUOTE BLOCK\"";
    string actual = StringExtensions.RemoveRedundantSpaces(source);
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
```

Comment: Not a duplicate of that question. This question is about parsing a string literal to remove spaces selectively.

Comment: @Prix Not a duplicate; this question involves more complicated parsing.

Comment: `'SELECT *    FROM...'` is within quotes; how should the method know that that's special? To do this perfectly, I think you'd need at least two parsers: one to parse the `call` syntax, one to parse the SQL syntax, and more for any other things you might want to intelligently remove redundant spaces from.

Comment: I need to fix my expected result. Give me a few minutes, plz

Comment: `'SELECT *    FROM TEMP WHERE NAME = 'SOME   VALUE'` is not quoted properly. Not sure if this plays into any testing you've done, but I imagine it would cause problems.

Comment: As an aside, what problem are you trying to solve?  Whitespace in commands should not matter, except within quoted strings, which you are excluding by definition.

Comment: I updated my example. I am crawling batch files and everything that they call. While I do that, I extract SQL and use the SQL Server DOM parser parse it. I'd like to leave the literals in the SQL text unchanged so I do not change literals. however, removing redundant spaces in the batch code will help me interpret it. I have been looking at command line parsers, too, but batch files aren't necessarily just commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a Brute Force method that may be the simplest (and could easily be turned into an extension method).  Note that if you have improperly quoted strings, this will not necessarily return what you are expecting (but will point out issues in the batch files that you are parsing).

```
    private static void TrimRedundantSpaces(string input)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(input);

        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        char previousChar = '\0';
        bool inSingleQuote = false;
        bool inDoubleQuote = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        {
            switch (input[i])
            {
                case '\'':
                    if (! inDoubleQuote)
                        inSingleQuote = !inSingleQuote;
                    output.Append(input[i]);
                    break;

                case '"':
                    if (! inSingleQuote)
                        inDoubleQuote = !inDoubleQuote;
                    output.Append(input[i]);
                    break;

                case ' ':
                    if ((previousChar != ' ') || inSingleQuote || inDoubleQuote)
                        output.Append(' ');
                    break;

                default:
                    output.Append(input[i]);
                    break;
            }

            previousChar = input[i];
        }

        Console.WriteLine(output.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TrimRedundantSpaces("sqlcmd.exe    -Q 'LEAVE     SQL TEXT HERE   UNCHANGED BECAUSE IT'S IN A DBL QUOTE BLOCK'");
        TrimRedundantSpaces("sqlcmd.exe    -Q \"LEAVE     SQL TEXT HERE   UNCHANGED BECAUSE IT'S IN A DBL QUOTE BLOCK\"");
        TrimRedundantSpaces("sqlcmd.exe    -Q \"LEAVE     'SQL TEXT' HERE   UNCHANGED BECAUSE IT'S IN A DBL QUOTE BLOCK\"");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Same brute force approach I was thinking but your code is cleaner.  I did make mine an extension method. Thanks